# How to create data set by the reference csv file

Tags: sas, sas-macro

```
data name
filename reference name  "filename.csv"
infile filename.csv dlm=",";
run;
```

what is wrong with the code?How to create data set by the reference csv file

Answer (score 1):

Place the `filename` statement before the `DATA` Step.

You will need an `INPUT` statement to read the data into variables,
or if the file has a header row use `Proc IMPORT` and the system will best guess the `input` needed.

Example 1

Presume file has no header row and there are 3 columns of numbers separated by commas

```
  filename myfile 'mydatafile.csv';
  data want;
    infile myfile dsd dlm=',';
    input x y z;
  run;
```

Example 2

Presume there is a header row

```
  filename myfile 'mydatafile.csv';
  proc import file=myfile replace out=want dbms=csv;
  run;
```

or

```
  * columns expected are known;
  filename myfile 'mydatafile.csv';
  data want;
    infile myfile dsd dlm=',' firstobs=2;
    input x y z;
  run;
```

NOTE

An `INFILE` statement can also directly refer to a file

```
   ...
   INFILE "filename.csv" ... ;
   ...
```